# How to use `systemd-ask-password-console.service`

Tags: systemd, password, console

How I am supposed to use `systemd-ask-password-console.service`? My aim is to trigger a password prompt and ask for input on *some* terminal.

Currently I am trying it like this:

1. Start `systemd-ask-password-console.service`.
2. Ensure that no other password agent is running: `ps aux | grep ask`
3. Ensure that no other password agent is to be started: `systemctl status systemd-ask*`
4. Execute `systemd-ask-password --no-tty "Password:"` to trigger the password agent.

Step 3 is waiting for an agent to return the password and finally times out. In the meantime the request can be seen within `/run/systemd/ask-password/`.

`systemctl status systemd-ask-password-console.service` shows:

```
● systemd-ask-password-console.service - Dispatch Password Requests to Console
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-ask-password-console.service; static; vendor preset: 
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-05-11 16:46:43 CEST; 6min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-ask-password-console.service(8)
 Main PID: 392 (systemd-tty-ask)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-ask-password-console.service
       ├─392 /bin/systemd-tty-ask-password-agent --watch --console
       └─393 /bin/systemd-tty-ask-password-agent --watch --console=/dev/tty1

May 11 16:46:43 debian systemd[1]: Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console.
```

I would expect that the running agent processes the request *and* that it will use some terminal (e.g. *tty1*) to ask for the password.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You might be interested in answer to my own question here: https://superuser.com/a/1788790/141399 I had the same questions as you. Basically a lot of the builtin units in systemd are never meant to be moved around and are purposely closely tied together. I had hoped systemd units was more reusable to be honest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> systemd-ask-password-console.service is a system service that queries the user for system passwords (such as hard disk encryption keys and SSL certificate passphrases) on the console. It is intended to be used **during boot** to ensure proper handling of passwords necessary for boot. systemd-ask-password-wall.service is a system service that informs all logged in users for system passwords via wall(1). It is intended to be used **after boot** to ensure that users are properly notified.

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-ask-password-console.service.html

because it is not possible to reliably read from the console while another process (`sh` or `login`) is already reading from the console.  More specifically, user input will be passed to only one process, and you cannot guess which process that will be.

Comment: I will accept your answer because you also pointed out why it is not expected to work after boot (after entering multi-user phase).

Comment: Hence, to get some terminal password agent processing requests after boot, I will need to start an agent on a dedicated terminal. Once again, that should be possible with the already existing *systemd* agent.

Answer (score 4):

> How I am supposed to use systemd-ask-password-console.service?

Long story short, you are not.

[`systemd-ask-password-console.service`(8)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-ask-password-console.service.html) is started automatically via its corresponding `.path` unit when someone makes an ask-password request. The ask-password agents are intended to be started simultaneously, and the agent which first reaches the user "wins".

> I would expect that the running agent processes the request and that it will use some terminal (e.g. tty1) to ask for the password.

This is correct. However, it won't ask for input on "any" terminal, which is pretty much impossible in current Linux for reasons @sourcejedi stated in [his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/443361/21885).

## Further reading

- ["Password Agents"](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PasswordAgents/). systemd documentation. freedesktop.org.

Comment: +1 For explicitly stating "no, it won't work" and pointing to the corresponding *systemd* documentation.